# How do I prevent a column in Silverlight xaml Grid from taking up the entire row?

Tags: xaml, silverlight-4.0

I want to display two columns in my Grid. The first is a textblock that is sometimes longer than the row meant to hold it. The second is a button. Is there a way to give the textblock as much room as possible while still leaving room for the button to go immediately after?

When I use the following code, the textblock will sometimes push the button outside the viewable area of the grid.

```
<Grid >
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Description}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <Button Margin="4,0" Height="0" Width="16" Grid.Column="1" MinWidth="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
</Grid>
```

I've tried setting the first column definition Width="*", but then the button is always at the very end of the row, when I want it next to the text. Any suggestions?

This is in Silverlight 4.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I want the grid to resize as the user changes the window size, so setting a hard limit on the grid size is no good. That being said, I was able to manually set the MaxWidth in the code behind when the TextBlock loads and when the window changes size. It's clunky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

**Following will surely work..**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="250">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Grid.Column="0" Text="Text Box" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Grid.Column="1" Content="Button" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="60"/>
</Grid>
```

**Add Following Line to xaml.cs file in constructor..**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBlock.MaxWidth = LayoutRoot.Width - button.Width;
}
```

Let me know if there is any issue with it.

Thanks..

Comment: This would limit the width to 250 px, when I want it to be able to expand or contract as the user changes window size. Sorry I forgot to mention that in the post. And I did find a way to do it, but it's a little clunky.